# Incrementing in an input()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a user input in my code that appears neatly in the terminal:

```
data_class = input('''What class do you want to assign to this data?
                            1   -   %s
                            2   -   %s
                            3   -   %s
                            4   -   %s
                            5   -   %s
                            6   -   %s
                            7   -   %s
                            8   -   %s
                            9   -   %s
                            10  -   %s
                            ''' % tuple(usb_paths))
```

What I'm wondering is if there is any way to shorten this code by creating a loop where the integer increments?

Something like (I know this doesn't make sense but..):

```
while i < len(usb_paths):
    data_class = input('''What class do you want to assign to this data?
                                i   -   %s
                                ''' % tuple(usb_paths))
    i += 1
```

This way if I add some new elements to usb_paths, it will correctly increase the amount of arguments in the input. Currently I have to add the following if my number of paths in usb_paths increases:

```
...
                            11  -  %s
                            ''' % tuple(usb_paths))
```

I'm using this method as it displays neatly in the terminal, any suggestions on how to achieve this more programmatically with similar indentation in the terminal are welcome.

Comment: Can we see an example of `usb-paths` ?

Comment: I think you can just concatenate the input  in a loop to get the desired string

Comment: Is usb_paths a list of strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use a `for` loop and string concatenation:

```
message = ""
for i in range(len(usb_paths)):
    message += str(i) + " - %s\n"

data_class = input(message)
```

This will start at 0 instead of 1. If you want it to start from 1, you can adjust the call to `range`.

Comment: Thanks! I changed this to ' message += '\t\t' + str(i) + " - %s\n" ' to keep the indentation. Appreciate the help